# How to change a variable equation so that one quantity impacts the outcome more than it currently is?

Tags: mean

Forgive my lack of vocabulary, I've never formally studied statistics. I'm currently working on a project involving quantifying genres of music, and there are only two variables at play: The Total Points that genre has received, and the Average Points that genre has received. Currently, I'm just taking the mean of these two quantities, but this has lead to the Final Points depending almost entirely on the total, rather than the average. See the attached picture for what I mean.
[image: Text]
How can I change the Final Points formula to rely more on the average?

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable.  What does it mean to "receive points"?  What is the "final points formula" you wish to change?  What are these "average points," "final points," and "expected variance" referred to in the graphics?  What do you mean by "rely ... on the average"?   What properties of music genres are you trying to quantify? Why?

Comment: The points are entirely arbitrary, they're based on ratings from users - a range from -32 to 26 (currently, only the positive values have been inputted.) Currently, the final score of points is entirely linear with the total points, enough to make the average points basically worthless in terms their use in data. I want to change this. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "taking the mean of these two quantities" you mean you are calculating the Final Points as the mean of the Total Points and the Average Points, then the graph you've labelled "Actual Variance" is exactly what you'd expect to see. If you think about the relationship between the total and the average then it should be easy to understand why (hint: look at the scales on the x-axis of your two graphs).

If you are mainly interested in the Average Points, then why not just use this value?

I'm not sure that combining the two values gives a meaningful result, but if you really want to do this, then you could weight one - e.g. calculate the Final Points (FP) by:

- either multiplying the Average Points (AP) by a constant: $FP_i = (TP_i + c \times AP_i) / 2$
- or dividing the Total Points (TP) by a constant: $FP_i = (TP_i / c + AP_i) / 2$

The larger the value you pick for $c$, the more weight you'll give to the Average Points.